# Customize Material UI Table styles - last-child

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to adjust the padding of Material UI `Table`.
`last-child` gets padding 24px which I want to adjust. I have tried to override the theme and to use `classes{{root: classes.xxx}}` but am not able to change it.

Below is the code I used for overriding the theme (I have also tried to override `MuiTableRow` and `MuiTableColumn`):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      root: {
        paddingTop: 4,
        paddingBottom: 4,
        '&  $lastChild': { paddingRight: '5px' },
      },
      paddingDefault: {
        padding: '40px 12px 40px 16px',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This is the CSS that I am trying to change (the last cell of each row in the table):

```css
.MuiTableCell-root-511:last-child {
    padding-right: 24px;
}
```

Hope someone can give a helping hand.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Thats the right approach, you just have a few syntax errors in your JSS.

The last child selector should be:

```js
'&:last-child': {}
```

Here a complete example

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      root: {
        paddingTop: 4,
        paddingBottom: 4,
        "&:last-child": {
          paddingRight: 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Material UI Override table padding on last child]

Comment: Thank you so much Luke!

Comment: It's called _Nesting selectors_ and documented by example only [➡️ here](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors)

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't want to override theme, you can achieve the same result by providing classes object prop as shown [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes).

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  cell: {
    '&:last-child': {
      paddingRight: 5,
    },
  },
});
```

Provide it to your `TableCell` as usual;

```
<TableCell className={classes.cell}>
```

This will override the `&:last-child` attribute of your cell. I've found this method to be a little more convenient when I'm not changing anything else in the theme.

Answer (score 4):

In **MUI v5**, you can use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) and select the last `TableCell` like this:

```
<Table
  sx={{
    '& .MuiTableCell-root:last-child': {
      bgcolor: 'pink',
    },
  }}
>
```

Or if you want to use `createTheme()` to override globally:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '&:last-child': {
            backgroundColor: 'tomato',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Fwiw I had to remove the space between the & and the . in "'& .MuiTableCell-root:last-child'"